# Is it possible to create an array or collection of functions in vb.net?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, function, collections

I'm writing a really basic function that sorts inbound emails to a group mailbox into folders based on who they're intended to be read by. It's a daft thing to need to do, as we all have our own email addresses, but companies often do daft things!

The criteria that determine "who the email is for" are quite complex, so I'm writing a series of simple functions to return if it's "for" a particular person

```
Function IsRichard(msg As Outlook.MailItem) As Boolean
    ...
End Function

Function IsTim(msg As Outlook.MailItem) As Boolean
   ...
End Function
```

At present I'm then running all of these in sequence in a control function `Function WhoIsItFor()`. However, this sub is now getting a bit long and ungainly, so I was wondering if it was possible to define an Array or Collection of Functions so that I can do something along the lines of:

```
Const AllFunctions as Function () = {IsRichard, IsTim ...}

Function WhoIsItFor(msg as Outlook.MailItem) as String
    
   For Each thisFunction as Function in AllFunctions
       if thisFunction(msg) then
          return (thisFunction.name)
       end if
   next

end function
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the AddressOf operator and the define the array type with the delegate Func:

```
Dim AllFunctions() As Func(Of Outlook.MailItem, Boolean) = {AddressOf IsRichard, AddressOf IsTim}

Function WhoIsItFor(msg As Outlook.MailItem) As String

    For Each thisFunction As Func(Of Outlook.MailItem, Boolean) In AllFunctions
        If thisFunction(msg) Then
            Return thisFunction.Method.Name
        End If
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: This is very close to correct, but did you test it first? It doesn't compile.

Comment: You could also avoid the `For` loop with this: `AllFunctions.Where(Function (f) f(msg)).Select(Function (f) f.Method.Name).FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: I just compiled it mocking Outlook.MailItem and worked. What error did you get?

Comment: Sorry, it's a compiler warning - c# would error, but VB seems a lot more lenient ad allows bad code. The warning is that not all code paths return a value. What happens if none of the functions return `True`?

Comment: The result would be Nothing as with your suggestion of replacing the For loop with the linq expression.

Comment: Yes, and I am suggesting that `Return Nothing` be explicitly put in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach is to create a class (vb.net is an object-oriented language ;)) to represent a person(or anything which can "react" to the email).
With such approach when you adding or removing persons you don't need to touch "main" code which handling emails.

```
' Create an abstraction to represent mail handler
Public Interface IMailHandler
  Function CanHandle(MailItem mail) As Boolean

  Sub Handle(MailItem mail)
End Interface

' Implement for Tim
Public Class Tim Inherits IMailPerson
  Public Function CanHandle(MailItem mail) As Boolean
    Return mail.Subject = "For Tim"
  End Function

  Public Sub Handle(MailItem mail)
    ' Move to Tim folder
  End Sub
End Class

' Implement for Bob
Public Class Bob Inherits IMailPerson
  Public Function CanHandle(MailItem mail) As Boolean
    ' Can be anything else
  End Function

  Public Sub Handle(MailItem mail)
    ' Delete Bob messages
  End Sub
End Class
```

Usage

```
Dim handlers As New List(Of IMailHandler) From { New Tim(), New Bob() }

var handler = handlers.
  Where(Function (h) h.CanHandle(mail)).
  DefaultIfEmpty(new DefaultHandler()).
  First()

handler.Handle(mail)
```

With approach above you can keep related logic in one place:

- decision about "can this mail be handled"
- actual action for this mail